# How to reinterpret data given by AVAudioRecorder as const char *?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, data-conversion, avaudiorecorder

**PROBLEM:**

The problem I am trying to solve is the following. I have audio data recorded by AVAudioRecorder. I can get the NSData by:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: self.audioRecorder.url];
```

But then I need to convert/reinterpret this NSData to a const char* form which would essentially look like

```
00 01 00 ff
```

which are bytes in hex or at least the equivalent string. They don't have to be actually in hex but just needs to be convertible to hex.

**QUESTION:**

My question is that the NSData has "\0" in them. So if I do something like this:

```
    NSUInteger len = [data length];
    Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
    memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
```

It would not work as the data will be cutoff when it meets the first "\0". I am super new to audio files, but I think it is because of the x00 values in the header. So basically, I don't want to them to be interpreted as "\0" but as "00". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not sure I understand, `'\0'` is the char for `0x00` hex, otherwise known as NULL.  Try this `NSLog(@"%.2x", '\0');`, all it does is convert to hex '\0' and log it, you will see they are the same.  More fun, `NSLog(@"%.2x %.2x %.2x", '\0', 0x00, 0);`

Comment: Yes, but I need the byte array to continue instead of stopping at a \0 I guess

Comment: The byte array will continue, just when you try to print it as a string it will not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question or what you are trying to do.  Your `memcpy` will copy all the bytes to the `byteData` buffer, it is only when you try to use the byteData buffer as a string (`char*`) and pass them into a format function (`NSLog(%"%s", val)`) will it cut off. If you want a string representation of the data as hex:

```
NSString* bytesToHex(Byte* bytes, NSUInteger count) {
    NSMutableString *hex = [NSMutableString string];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) [hex appendFormat:@"%.2x " , *(bytes+i)];
    return hex;
}

NSString* dataToHex(NSData* data) {
    return bytesToHex((Byte*)data.bytes, data.length);
}
```

will do it, ie:

```
Byte* bytes = (Byte*)"t\0h\0i\0s\0 i\0s\0 a\0 t\0e\0st";
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:24];

NSLog(@"%@",NSLog(@"%@", dataToHex(data));
```

will print:

```
74 00 68 00 69 00 73 00 20 69 00 73 00 20 61 00 20 74 00 65 00 73 74 00
```

or

```
Byte* bytes = (Byte*)"t\0h\0i\0s\0 i\0s\0 a\0 t\0e\0st";
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:24];
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
NSLog(@"%@", bytesToHex(byteData, len));
```

will print:

```
74 00 68 00 69 00 73 00 20 69 00 73 00 20 61 00 20 74 00 65 00 73 74 00
```

**Just remembered something**

Even easier, if you use the NSData description property, it gives you the data in hex already!

```
Byte* bytes = (Byte*)"t\0h\0i\0s\0 i\0s\0 a\0 t\0e\0st";
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:24];

NSLog(@"%@", data.description);
```

Will print

```
<74006800 69007300 20690073 00206100 20740065 00737400>
```

Not as pretty, but the same thing...